# How to transfer domain from Godaddy to another provider

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registrar

I'm currently using godaddy for all of my company domains, and I'm very unsatisfied with their service, specially with their site, so we are trying to migrate those domains to another provider. The question is, How do I transfer my domains to another domain registrar? I'm not talking about transferring domain records (A, MX...) but to use the same domains with another provider, and redo all the configuration again.

For example, one of our blogs is hosted in Slicehost and we feel very confortable with their record editing tool.

As I have read prowebmasters I can see other people not very satisfied with Godaddy service. Thanks!

**edit:** Thanks for the answers, they were all very informative.

Comment: Do note that if you're transferring a domain within 45 days of it's renewal date, you won't have another year added to your registration, and your former registrar may or may not refund you.

Have a read at [ICANN][1] and [WHT][2] for more details.

[1]: http://www.icann.org/en/announcements/advisory-06jun02.htm
[2]: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=577151

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Unlock the domain via GoDaddy's panel if they happen to be locked.
2. Update all the contact info and email address.  It needs to be accurate in case trouble occurs.
3. Get the authorization code or EPP from GoDaddy.com
4. Have your new host initiate the transfer (this will likely cost you a yearly fee at the new place)

You will have to supply the new registrar the code and they can finish the transfer.

Answer (score 2):

Most domains are "locked" so you will first need to unlock it through your GoDaddy domain control panel. Then initiate a "domain transfer" from your new registrar. You will get a few emails to confirm the transfer and you will need the codes included in those emails to complete the transfer.

It's pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically from Godaddy -> Another Registrar you can follow their help guide: http://help.godaddy.com/article/3560